# Mysql make AVG return null if any value is null

Tags: mysql, average

I'm trying to take an `AVG` from one of my columns in MySQL. However, the calculation must be done in another way if some of the values are `null`. So, I'm trying to make this:

I want `SELECT AVG(amount) from sales` to return `NULL` if any row in the sales table has `amount` `NULL`. Can this be done?

Comment: you can do conditionals in the select in mysql

Comment: Can you do this with PHP?

Comment: Try to use SELECT AVG(IFNULL(amount,0)) from sales.

Comment: Do you mean "amount 0" or "amount NULL"? Zero and NULL are not the same...

Comment: So you want null values to be included in the denominator when calculating the average?  Records AVG(1,2,3,4, NULL) would yield NULL but the way you want it it would be 2 (1+2+3+4+0)=10/5 or do you want (1+2+3+4)/4=(10/4 or 2.5)?

Comment: No, I want this: If I have AVG(1,2,3,4,NULL) it should return NULL. If I have AVG(1,2,3,4) it should return 10/4 = 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with (it counts nulls as zeros):

```
SELECT AVG(IFNULL(amount,0)) from sales
```

Edited (misinterpreted the question before):

```
SELECT IF(sum(amount is NULL), NULL, AVG(amount)) from sales
```

Comment: This counts the Nulls as ceros, I want the result of the `AVG` to be null if any value is null.

Comment: @JavierEnríquez, sorry for mistake, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM Sales
                  WHERE amount = 0 OR amount IS NULL) <> 0 
                  THEN NULL 
            ELSE AVG(amount)  END
FROM Sales
```

The above uses a sub-query in a `CASE` expression to check for `0` or `NULL` values. If *any* one value of `amount` field is `0` or `NULL` then the whole average is returned as `NULL`, otherwise the average value of `amount` is returned.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e120f/1)

Comment: I thought in this approach. The problem is, that my query is not that simple. I has joins and some wheres. With this approach I would have to replicate the query in the subquery, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's several ways to do this... This is one way.

I use a cross join to return the same value for all records if that value is > than 1 then a null record exists and I used a case statement to negate the avg and instead return null.  This could just as easily be done in a function call..

```
SELECT case when B.c>1 then null else avg(amount) end as myAvg 
FROM Sales 
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT count(*) c FROM Sales 
  WHERE amount is null) B
GROUP BY  B.C
```